# Is this c# code enough to handle globalization?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, datetime

My C# winforms program will be used in following countries

```
United Kingdom  : date format day-month-year , currency separator is '.'
United States   : date format month-day-year , currency separator is '.'
Denmark         : date format day-month-year , currency separator is ','
```

I want to make the program run properly irrespective of what regional settings are on users computer. My main concern is handling date format and currency fields
(Language translation is not a problem because the program will only show English text)

To do this I have decided that all dates in the database will be saved with `yyyy-mm-dd` format and all decimal fields will be saved with `.` as separator.
I created the database with `Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS` collation .
So I am assuming the data will be saved in the above `datetime` format & decimal format without me requiring to do anything special.

I have put the following code in my program

```
var cult = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cult;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cult;

CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cult;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cult;
```

Please help me by telling from your experience if the above code is enough to make my program safe

Comment: I hope your database doesn't really store decimals and dates as string columns.

Comment: Henk  - no , all dates are stored in datetime column and decimals and currency values are stored in decimal columns

Comment: Then _dates in the database will be saved with yyyy-mm-dd format_ does not apply.

Comment: in which format does it get stored in ? do you mean I wont be able to write queries like this  select * from customer where dob= '2012-10-15' if i want to get all customers whose date of birth is 15th October 2012 ?

Comment: The queries depend on what your SQL engine is willing to understand (the only standardized format is US m/d/y). It does not depend on the locale of the client(s).

Comment: @HenkHolterman - no, it depends on the locale of the db server. In the UK m/d/y will be interpreted as d/m/y. The only standard is yyyy-mm-dd: I've never seen that misunderstood.

Comment: We used date formatting when we displayed to the user, because sometimes we may use a date picker to choose the date

Comment: does that mean that I have to format and pass the dates as string and never use sqlparameters ?

Comment: @Cheryl: no, you pass parameters but since queries are strings you somoehow HAVE to pass a datetime as string. And the universal format (which btw is automatically used by or mappers) of passsing a datetime so that is it understood no matter of locales is `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss` e.g. `2025-03-27T15:00:00`

Comment: @Cheryl - you should *always* use SQL Parameters.  When you assign a value to the parameter, that should be a *native* value, not a string (unless you're passing strings like "abcd", of course)

Answer (score 2):

Culture applies *only* in the following two scenarios:

- Converting a string representation of a value to a native format, which is called "parsing".
- Converting the native format of a value to a string representation, which is called "formatting".

When you store a `datetime` or a `decimal` or some other type into the database, it is stored in a *native* format.  In a SQL database, this is usually some compact binary value that you will never work with directly.

Consider the following SQL:

```sql
declare @dt datetime
set @dt = '01/02/2015 12:34:56'
select @dt
```

In the first line, we declare a variable of type `datetime`.  It's not a string, it's a specific data type that takes up 8 bytes of memory or disk.

In the second line, we assign a string value to the variable.  SQL *parses* the string, converting it to a `datetime` so it can be stored in the `@dt` variable.  The actual value stored has a hexadecimal representation of `0x0000A41400CF5940`.

When it did the parsing, the current culture for the environment where the code was running was applied.  Because I am in the USA, it interpreted the date as January 2nd.  If I was in Europe, it would interpret the date as February 1st (changing the internal value to `0x0000A43200CF5940`).

Using dates in `yyyy-mm-dd` format will avoid misinterpretation, but that does not mean that the actual value is *stored* as a string in that format.  It's just that the format is unambiguous, so it will be *parsed* the same way regardless of culture.

In the third line of code above, we select the variable to include it in a result set.  Though we are selecting it in its native form without any conversion, we ultimately *see* it in a string representation.  If you are running the query in a tool such as SQL Server Management Studio, the output window will *format* the native values to strings so you can read them.  When doing so, the current culture is again applied.  SQL's default is to show dates in `yyyy-mm-dd` format, rather than the culture-specific format.  But other values, such as decimals, will use the current culture's separator.

If instead of running this in SSMS you actually retrieved the results through your *own* code in a `SqlDataReader` (for example), then formatting never occurs.  The reader maps SQL's binary native value directly to the appropriate .NET native type, using [the mappings shown here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729.aspx).  A SQL `datetime` gets natively mapped to a .NET `DateTime`.

```csharp
DateTime dt = (DateTime) reader["dt"];
```

Now quite often, you see someone doing silly things like this:

```csharp
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["dt"].ToString());
```

This is wasteful because the value is *already* a `DateTime`, and this code would use the current culture to format the string, then use it again to parse the string.  That's a lot of string manipulation for no reason whatsoever.

Ultimately, in your .NET code, you will end up using that `DateTime` value and converting it to a string somewhere for output.  When you do, *that's* when you apply the current culture.

Likewise, when you receive an input string from your user (such as when filling out a form), you *parse* the value to a `DateTime` using the current culture again.

Native data types *are not strings* - and are thus not affected by culture.

Notes:

- If you want to see the hexadecimal representation of the native binary form of any SQL data type, you can use something like: `select convert(varbinary, @dt)`
- Be aware of whatever the native format is for anywhere you are working.  If you're writing to an http stream, a text file, or a document database, etc., the string representation does *indeed* matter, because a string *is* the native format in those scenarios.

And just to prove this applies to more than dates, consider:

```sql
select 123, 123.45, convert(varbinary, 123), convert(varbinary, 123.45)

--results:    123    123.45    0x0000007B    0x0502000139300000
```

Comment: Matt, you mentioned `SSMS you actually retrieved the results through your code in a SqlDataReader`. Just wonder, where is the information online available?

Comment: @Love - sorry, I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: I meant if you run a query in `SSMS`, the under hood code actually using `SqlDataReader` to retrieve the result? In another word, if we inspect the dlls of `SSMS` by red gate reflection or `IL Spy` . It contains `SqlDataReader`. Is that your meaning?

Comment: I have no idea what SSMS does under the hood.  I was comparing looking a the results in SSMS which will show formatted strings, vs querying SQL from a custom .net app.  Not sure how you interpreted it as diving into internals of SSMS.

Comment: No worry about, I misunderstood it.